# Geo Dynamic Web Page being indexed by Google in San Francisco

Tags: html, geolocation, seo

I run a website that is dynamic based on your geo, ie if you go to http://example.com/ and you are in San Francisco it will present you with San Francisco content and I'll put San Francisco in the title.

My issue is that Google is in San Francisco and as such indexes the San Francisco version of the site showing the city in the search results. Is there anyway to keep my current functionality and have Google index a generic version of the site? One thing I've tried to do is detect whether or not the user is a bot by checking the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` but this hasn't appeared to work.

Comment: Just a thought - can you look at your log, see Google's crawler IP and then update your site so it will serve some generic content if visitor is coming from that Google's IP. Like if Google crawler IP is normally 111.111.111.xxx, than serve generic content for visitor with that IP (all IPs that are like 111.111.111.xxx probably). I don't really know if it's doable or whether it'll work. Just a vague idea.

Answer (score 0):

No it wont work.

If you need to make it work, then you need to work on off page SEO techniques for specific keywords and specific pages.

Comment: I'm not worried about indexing for keywords, just in making the results for mysite.com not be geo-specific.